# Списки. Передача данных Python

Tags: python

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. У меня есть список, в ячейки которого я загружаю следующие данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это пример одной ячейки. После я хочу с каждой ячейки передать данные в два других списка где в 1 буду хранить данные по километрам(Только численное значение), во 2 буду хранить данные по минутам(Так же только число). Вот как их получить и передать в другие списки - я понять не могу...
Письменный вид данных, для удобства.

```
[[<div class="_zgp22zy" tabindex="0"><div class="_1vkmpb5"><div class="_13amzhkw"><svg fill="currentColor" height="24" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M19.38 11L18 7a14.52 14.52 0 0 0-6-1 14.52 14.52 0 0 0-6 1l-1.35 4H3v2l1 1v6h2a1 1 0 0 0 1-1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h2v-6l1-1v-2zM7.59 8.55A15.65 15.65 0 0 1 12 8a16.07 16.07 0 0 1 4.42.55L18 13H6.09zM7 17a1 1 0 1 1 1-1 1 1 0 0 1-1 1zm10 0a1 1 0 1 1 1-1 1 1 0 0 1-1 1z"></path></svg></div><div class="_mfyskr"><div class="_iilzoe9">26 мин</div><div class="_sgs1pz">14 километров</div></div><div class="_1kgl53z">с учётом пробок</div></div></div>]]
```

Вот сам код программы

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import lxml
import time
import random
import pyautogui
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup




def hashtag_search(number):
    i = 0
    value = []
    minutikm=[]
    heads = []
    #klm=[]
    #Вводим адресса
    while i < number:
        input_string = input("Введите адрес -")
        value.append(input_string)
        i += 1
    browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Stream\pythonProject\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
    i=0
    #Запускаем эмуляцию работы с браузером
    try:
        #Запускаем цикл в котором будем последовательно все пути между адрессами
      while i<number-1:
          j=i+1
          while j<number:
#запускаем 2 гис
            browser.get('https://2gis.ru/volgograd/directions')
            time.sleep(1)
#Вводим первый адресс
            value_input = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_g1gj1v')
            value_input.clear()
            value_input.send_keys(value[i])
            time.sleep(1)
#Вводим второй адресс
            value_input = browser.find_element_by_class_name('_g1gj1v')
            value_input.clear()
            value_input.send_keys(value[j])
#подверждаем адресса, чтобы браузер показал расстояние и время
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.press('enter')
            time.sleep(1)
# Создаем суп, для получения данных
            soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
            time.sleep(random.randrange(10, 15))
#считываем данные из кратчайшего пути
            minutikm.append(soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"_zgp22zy"}))
            #print(minutikm)
            head = soup.find('div', class_='_sgs1pz')

            heads.append(head.string)
            print(heads)


            #Класс первых данных _zgp22zy

            j+=1

          i+=1

#Для закрытия браузера
    except Exception as ex:
      print(ex)
      browser.close()
      browser.quit()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Вводим сколько адрессов будем вводить
    number = int(input("Введите колличество адресов"))
    hashtag_search(number)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что Вы пытаетесь сделать. Приложите пример кода

Comment: Это результат парсинга? Такой список в код не вставить :)

Comment: Да,  я это парсил с сайта.  Ну когда мало знаешь выходят интересные вещи) ибо я закинул это в список.  soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
            time.sleep(random.randrange(10, 15))
            minutikm.append(soup.find_all(attrs={"class":"_zgp22zy"}))
            print(minutikm)

Comment: Я бы использовал `extend`: `minutikm.extend`, а то у вас получает список из списков, не думаю, что так задумывалось :)

Comment: Кст, советую добавить `r` к строке пути: `webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Stream\pythonProject\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')`, это убережет от потенциальных проблем с экранированием

Comment: Благодарю за советы) Действительно не хотел список в список закидывать...

Comment: почему бы не парсить и записывать в списки только значащие данные, а не soup?